Rees algebra, symmetric algebra and polynomial ring isomoporhisms $(A\oplus I\oplus I^2\ldots \cong A[X_1\ldots,X_n]/J)$
If $I=(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)\subset A$ is generated by a regular sequence, then $$A\oplus I\oplus I^2\ldots \cong A[X_1\ldots,X_n]/J$$
where $J$ is generated by the $2\times 2$ minors of
$$\begin{pmatrix}
  x_1 &\ldots  &x_2 \\ 
  X_1&\ldots  &X_n \\ 
\end{pmatrix}.$$

My attempt:
The Rees algebra $A\oplus I\oplus I^2\oplus \ldots$ is isomorphic to the algebra
$A\oplus I\oplus I^{\otimes 2}\oplus I^{\otimes 3}\oplus\ldots$ modulo the all the relations of the form $x_i\otimes x_j-x_j\otimes x_i$
by sending $x_1x_2\ldots x_n\mapsto x_1\otimes x_2\ldots \otimes x_n$
Now this algebra is canonically isomorphic to $A[X_1\ldots,X_n]/J$ by $[x_i]\mapsto [X_i]$

Another approach I have is to consider $$\phi:A[X_1,\ldots, X_n]\twoheadrightarrow A\oplus I\oplus I^2\oplus \ldots$$
$$X_i\mapsto x_i $$
then since $X_i\mapsto x_i,  \; \phi(X_ix_j-X_jx_i)=x_ix_j-x_jx_i$ and since we are in commutative case   $x_ix_j-x_jx_i=0$
So $(X_ix_j-X_jx_i\mid i,j \in [n])\subseteq \ker\phi$ but I can't show the other inclusion. An idea would be to consider $P\in \ker\phi $ and $P\notin (X_ix_j-X_jx_i\mid i,j \in [n])$ then $\phi(P)=0$ but wouldn't that mean we have zero divisors ?
Any suggestions ?
