Koszul relations of a regular sequence $x_ix_j-x_jx_i=0$
Could someone explain what we mean by the term "Koszul relation"  here
?
What does the author mean when he writes "for regular sequence the Koszul complex is exact so that the relations between the $_$
are only the Koszul relations $__−__=0$
so that the equations of the Rees algebra are the $__−__=0$
."

In general a Kosuzul complex of the pair $(\mathbf{x},M)$, where $\textbf{x} = \{x_1,...,x_n\}$ is an $R$-sequence (not necessarily $M$-regular) and $M$ is an $R$-module,  is a chain complex $K_{\bullet}(\textbf{x},M) $ where $K_i = \bigwedge^i M^n \cong M^{\binom{n}{i}}$ for $1\leq i \leq n$, $K_0 = M$ and  $K_i = 0$ otherwise. Clearly $M^{\binom{n}{i}}$ is generated by $m \otimes (e_{j_1} \wedge \dots \wedge e_{j_i})$, with $m \in M$ and $e_{j_1} \wedge \dots \wedge e_{j_i}\in A^{\binom{n}{i}}$ with $j_n \neq j_m, \forall m,n \leq i$ and $j_m \leq j_n$ if $m <n$. And the boundary map $d_i : K_{i+1} \rightarrow K_i$ is given by $d(m \otimes (e_{j_1} \wedge\dots\wedge e_{j_i})) = \sum_{k=1}^i (-1)^{k-1} x_{j_k} \cdot m \otimes e_{j_1}\wedge \dots\wedge \hat{e_{j_{i}}} \wedge\dots\wedge e_{j_{i}}$
If x is an $M$-regular sequence, then one can show that $K_{\bullet} (\textbf{x},M) \rightarrow M$ is an exact sequence.
Now back to the problem in the link. We have $K_1 = M^n, K_0 = M$ and $d_0(m \otimes e_i) = x_im_i$. In fact, one may see that $d_0(\sum_{i=1}^n r_i m_i \otimes e_1) =0 \iff \sum_{i=1}^n r_i(x_im_i) = 0$. Thus to understand the linear equations of the form  $\sum_{i=1}^n r_i(x_im_i) = 0$, it suffices to understand $\ker d_0$. If x is regular, then $\ker d_0 = \text{im}d_1$, and the latter one is in fact generated by $x_i m \otimes e_j - x_j m \otimes e_i$, thus those unique linear relations are $(x_ix_j-x_jx_i) \cdot m, \forall m \in M$ In the case of this problem, I think it suffices to let $M = A/I$ and the relations are $x_ix_j-x_jx_i$.

Thank you for providing such a thorough and motivating response! I was trying to come up with such an answer, how to connect the exactness and the tensors but it was too much. but my first attempt had a more tensor algebra approach. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4910684/rees-algebra-symmetric-algebra-and-polynomial-ring-isomoporhisms-a-oplus-i-op

@領域展開 In fact, I think you are on the right approach, but you might just need something called double chain complex: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0FNB.If you are Koszul complexes, an interesting reference can be Cohen-Macaulay rings by Bruns&Herzog where there is an explicit explanation about the relation between regular sequence and Koszul complex.

I will try to look at the reference and for more details. The link you are posting seems to be invalid.

https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0FNB  If should work this time

Who is $A$ in this answer?
